# How can you use perl and regex to append character at end of each new line between match

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I am using `bash` `perl` and `sed` to take GraphQL queries and convert them to TypeScript types. I have it all figured out except one piece - I cannot figure out how to insert a comma at the end of each line within a regex match.

This is the raw `*.graphqls` text that I'm successfully matching:

```
enum ContentType {
    LESSON
    WARMUP
    QUIZ
    PROJECT
}
```

The Regex that makes the match (selects everything between and including `enum` and `}` ):

`s/(?s)(?=enum).*?(})`

I can easily replace this entire segment with `bash` and `perl`:

```
ENUM_MATCH="s/(?s)(?=enum).*?(})/replacement/"

perl -i -0pe "${ENUM_MATCH}" "${FULL_PATH}"
```

But what I need to do is replace this enum text with the same text, except with a comma on each enum line item - end result would look like this:

```
enum ContentType {
    LESSON,
    WARMUP,
    QUIZ,
    PROJECT
}
```

Comment: Don't use `ALL_UPPERCASE` for your shell variables; those are reserved for the system.

Comment: By the way, `-0` (NUL-terminated lines) should be `-0777` (slurp mode)

Comment: You can use a `sub` statement with the pattern `(?<=\w)\n` substituting with `,`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/93iF2C/2

Comment: Consider allowing a trailing comma (after `PROJECT`), which is legal as of C99 and C++11. A lot of work will be considerably smoother.

Comment: @melpomene, Where do you read that *ALL_UPPERCASE* vars are *reserved* for the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a trailing comma (after `PROJECT`) is allowed, which is legal as of C99 and C++11

```
perl -i -pe'if ($r = /^\s*enum/ .. /}\s*$/) { s/$/,/ if $r!=1 && $r!~/E0$/ }' file
```

This uses [range operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators), and its return with which to exclude its first and last line.

Answer (score 0):

With trailing comma:

```
s{enum[^{]*\{\K([^}]*)}{ $1 =~ s/\n/,\n/gr }seg
```

Without:

```
s{enum[^{]*\{\K([^}]*)}{ $1 =~ s/\n/,\n/gr =~ s/,(?=[^,]*\z// }seg
```

Answer (score 0):

an awk one-liner works for your example:

```
 awk '/enum .*\{/{print;next}p{print p (/\}/?"":",")}{p=$0}END{print p}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If `,` is allowed after `PROJECT`:

```
awk '$1=="}"{f=0} f{$0=$0 ","} $1=="enum"{f=1} 1' data
```